# Sublime Text 3: Prevent having same file in multiple windows

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I use Sublime Text to edit files simultaneously on two monitors, by using two separate Sublime windows (by tearing away a tab). But if I have file A open in Sublime, then I tear away that tab, I can open file A again in the first window, and now I have two views into the same file--but they're not synced! So if I edit in the first window and save it, then edit in the second window and save it, my first window's changes are overwritten.

Sometimes I overlook that I already have a file open, and wind up losing work. Is there some way to prevent this from happening?